# Set role for all users using the console

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, console, cancan

What I'm trying to do is set role to "user" for all users, but I haven't used the console or Ruby much, which should be clear from the way I'm trying to use them below.

I had hoped something like this would work:

```
u=User.all
u.role.name="user"
```

But, clearly, that's not working and I'm not sure how to proceed.

I'm using CanCan with an ability model and setting the role name by a "name" column in roles. users have many roles through assignments

user.rb

```
has_many :assignments
has_many :roles, :through => :assignments
```

Here's how everything is set up:

assignment.rb

```
class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :role
end
```

ability.rb

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # in case of guest
    if user.has_role? :admin
      can :manage, :all
    #else
     # can :read, :all
  end
  end
end
```

role.rb

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users, :join_table => :users_roles
  belongs_to :resource, :polymorphic => true
end
```

roles schema

```
  # == Schema Information
  #
  # Table name: roles
  #
  #  id            :integer         not null, primary key
  #  name          :string(255)
  #  resource_id   :integer
  #  resource_type :string(255)
  #  created_at    :datetime        not null
  #  updated_at    :datetime        not null
  #
```

Can you let me know how I would set the role name for all users using console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`update_all`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-update_all):

```
role = Role.find_by_name 'user'
User.update_all :role => role
```

However, `update_all` will not trigger ActiveRecord callbacks, so if you need those you instead need to iterate over all users:

```
role = Role.find_by_name 'user'
User.find_each do |user|
  user.role = role
  user.save
end
```

[`User.find_each`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_each) loads users in batches to minimize memory usage if you have more than 1000 users.

Comment: Also available is the `:batch_size` option for #find_each, and the [#find_in_batches](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-multiple-objects-in-batches) method.

Comment: I think this would work but my roles are assigned to users through assignments "has_many :roles, :through => :assignments" getting an error "ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  column "role" of relation "users" does not exist"

Comment: Tried the second suggestion to see if that would work and get this error "NoMethodError: undefined method `role=' for #<User:0x007f8d92894bb8>"

Comment: if the association is has_many, make sure you use the plural, user.roles.